# Set max size for MarkLogic log file(s)

Tags: logging, size, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

We have some logfiles that will exceed the 1GB for a specific day in our development environment. 
Can we set a size limit, for example 250MB, so that the logfile will continue logging within a newly created log file when the size limit is reached. 
This will generate in our case 4 logfiles for a specific day, instead of 1 huge logfile..

Comment: Please provide more information about the log files. Are you referring to the built-in logging via `xdmp:log`, or do you have your own logging system? If the latter, provide examples with explanations.

Comment: we are using the xdmp:log statements to write log information.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading this section in the Admin guide about Log Files:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/logfiles

To sum up: you don't have much control over the log files written to disk, but you might be able to tap into the System Log to which MarkLogic also sends log messages.

HTH!